# Can Google Sheets be used as "Multi-user" database?

Tags: database, google-sheets, multi-user

Say I have an App and I want to use Google sheet as my backend database.
Can I let the different users use their own Google sheets by logging in their own Google account?
I read some articles about using Google sheet as a backend database, but almost all of them are about creating the Google sheet with your own Google account.

I know Google Drive can let you save user-specific data to user's own space. I am not sure if Google Sheets can do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's a very abstract question, but yes (it depends). after that, all you need to do is collect all the data into a master spreadsheet with `IMPORTRANGE` formulas:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL-or-ID", "Sheet1!A1:Z")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I want is that I can save data to user's own Google sheets. That way I don't need to worry about the storage space too much. And it also gives users more privacies since all data is in users' space.

Comment: Google Sheets as files are free of storage "weight" - they sit on Google Drive and you can have billions of them and it will take up exactly 0 bytes of Drive space

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know I can definitely do it with a master spreadsheet. But is it possible to save data to user's own Google Sheets by let user to log into his/her own Google account?

Comment: sure, you can give away individual sheets to users (or even whole spreadsheets) and require from them to be logged in

Comment: Thanks for your help!